# How to split two items inside a JSON array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, split

This is my code:

```
$scope.center_name = [];
      $scope.stats = ["Stats"];
      $scope.totMemCenterData = [];


      var query = "SELECT count(*) as tot_mem, centers.name as center_name FROM mem_groups "
    + "INNER JOIN centers ON mem_groups.center_id=centers.id GROUP BY centers.id";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
      .then(function(res){
          if (res.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            $scope.totMemCenterData = res.rows.item(i);
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.totMemCenterData));

          }
        }
      }, function(err){
          // $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
          console.log(err.message);
      });
```

This is the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.totMemCenterData));` :

```
{"center_name":"AFG - ANONANG","tot_mem":6}
{"center_name":"BAM - BUENAVISTA","tot_mem":3}
{"center_name":"GHT - TAGAS","tot_mem":2}
```

I want to put all center_names in one array also the tot_mem on another array. I want it to be like:

Centers: "AFG - ANONANG", "BAM - BUENAVISTA", "GHT - TAGAS"
Tot_mem: 6, 3, 2
I'm gonna put those values on a chart. Centers on the x-axis and tot_mem on the y-axis

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks! @Sajeetharan

Comment: mark as answer if it has helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
  $scope.center_names = [];
  $scope.tot_mem = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.sampleTest, function(key, value) {
  $scope.center_names.push(key["center_name"]);
  $scope.tot_mem.push(key["tot_mem"]);
  });
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sampleTest = [{
    "center_name": "AFG - ANONANG",
    "tot_mem": 6
  }, {
    "center_name": "BAM - BUENAVISTA",
    "tot_mem": 3
  }, {
    "center_name": "GHT - TAGAS",
    "tot_mem": 2
  }];
  $scope.center_names = [];
  $scope.tot_mem = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.sampleTest, function(key, value) {
      $scope.center_names.push(key["center_name"]);
      $scope.tot_mem.push(key["tot_mem"]);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1> Center names </h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in center_names">
      {{item}}
      </div>
   <h1> Total memory </h1>
   <div ng-repeat="tot in tot_mem">
      {{tot}}
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some Observations :**

- > TypeError: res.rows.item is not a function

  So, use this `res.rows.item[i]` instead of `res.rows.item(i).`
- Why `JSON.stringify` **?** As you have to iterate each object to create two different arrays based on the keys. So, leave `$scope.totMemCenterData` as it is.
- Instead of checking the length of `res.rows.length` check the length of items(`res.rows.item.length`) as you are going to iterate items.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    var res = {
 "rows": {
  "item": [{
   "center_name": "AFG - ANONANG",
   "tot_mem": 6
  }, {
   "center_name": "BAM - BUENAVISTA",
   "tot_mem": 3
  }, {
   "center_name": "GHT - TAGAS",
   "tot_mem": 2
  }]
 }
};

$scope.center_names = [];
$scope.tot_mem = [];
   
for (var i=0; i < res.rows.item.length; i++) {
    $scope.totMemCenterData = res.rows.item[i];
    $scope.center_names.push($scope.totMemCenterData.center_name);
    $scope.tot_mem.push($scope.totMemCenterData.tot_mem);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<b>Center Names :</b>
<div ng-repeat="names in center_names">
{{names}}
</div>
<b>Total Mem :</b>
<div ng-repeat="item in tot_mem">
{{item}}
</div>
</div>
```